# SQL with Count column on how many times a field appears in the same table

Tags: sql, select, count

I have a database table (visitlog) with page hits on my webpage. I have illustrated a simplified example below (yeah, I know that the IP:s are invalid... it's just a simplified example)

```
id    ip              date
================================
1     123.123.123     2013-01-01
2     123.123.123     2013-01-05
3     234.234.234     2013-01-22
4     45.67.89        2013-04-04
5     123.123.123     2013-12-25
```

I want a SELECT statement that adds a counter column that shows how many times the IP on that row exists in the table:

```
date         ip            no_of_visits
=======================================
2013-01-01   123.123.123    3
2013-01-05   123.123.123    3
2013-01-22   234.234.234    1
2013-04-04   45.67.89       1
2013-12-25   123.123.123    3
```

I.e. "SELECT date, ip, *[some count statement here]* FROM visitlog"

I don't want to group the IP rows. The ordinary COUNT-function doesn't work for this...

Comment: Why don't you want to group the IPs? My first guess would be that grouping by date and IP should match your needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a correlated sub-select to count:

```
SELECT date, ip, (select count(*) from visitlog v2
                  where v1.ip = v2.ip) as no_of_visits
FROM visitlog v1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT date, ip, count(*) 
FROM visitlog 
GROUP BY date, ip
```

That should work just fine. Unless I am missing something here.

EDIT: Oh! I understand what you meant here. I would accept jarls answer, that makes the most sense to give you a record per ip and date but the count is per ip.